# Server sent event from another client in java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to do a interaction like this?:

Client A open the comunication to the server (invokes the URI http://xxx/eventA), so it is waiting for a event.
Client B send a request to the server (http://xxx/eventB) to start an event.
The server take this request and send to the client A this event

As far I saw about SSE, the client open a conection and the server is sending events but in the same connection. Is it possible to do the described scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how does the server know which client to send the event to?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I want to know, in the documentation I found about SSE, I only saw that the server reply to the client that started the connection, I don't know how from the server you can choose a client to send the event to.